# Unsure of calculation step in polygon formula

Tags: python

The final step seen on [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/r%20%3D%5Cfrac%7B120%7D%7B2sin%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B180%C2%B0%7D%7B105%7D%5Cright)%7D?or=input): is a conversion to decimal to get Radius = 2005.65151, which I'm not sure how to recreate or if there's a step in between.

The result I have so far (RadiusD) prints a fraction.

[Image: Polygon formula where S = side length. N = num sides, r = radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ5f6.jpg)

Error in this code:

```
import math
from fractions import Fraction, Decimal

def TestRadius():
    HalfSideLen = 120/2
        #60
    edgeNum2Radians = math.radians(105)     #Edge count
    Radians = math.pi/edgeNum2Radians       # correct so far
        # 1.7142857142857142
    Radius = HalfSideLen / math.sin(Radians)    
    RadiusD = Decimal(HalfSideLen / math.sin(Radians))
        #1066491443117295/17592186044416
    # wanting r = 2005.65151
    print(RadiusD)
print(TestRadius())
```

My math is very poor, thanks for your help

Corrected by @ytung-dev. Somehow step 3 was returning a correct result so I didn't look too close at Step 2, where actually it was the error.

```
import math
def TestRadius():
    HalfSideLen = 120/2
    edgeNum = 105     
    Radians = math.pi/edgeNum       
    Radius = HalfSideLen / math.sin(Radians)    
    print(Radius)
print(TestRadius())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import math

def fx(s,n):
    return s / ( 2 * math.sin(math.pi/n) )

print(fx(120, 105))

# 2005.65
```

Few things to note:

1. `math.sin()` use **radian**
2. sin() in *symbolab* use **degree**
3. equation in your image use **degree**
4. 180 deg = `math.pi` rad

What is wrong in your script is that `edgeNum` is a counting number not an angle, so you should not convert it to radian. The only degree-radian conversion you should handle is the 180 deg in the equation.

So, to make your equation work in python, you simply change the 180 deg in the equation to `math.pi`.